# Can a PHP function return a reference to a static object?

Tags: php, static

Say I have a static object:

```
class everything{
    public static function must(){
        return "go!";
    }
}
```

When I do this:

```
echo everything::must();
```

I get the response:

```
go!
```

Which is the expected behavior.

---

Now, for my own reasons (legacy code support) I'd like to be able to call that static object from the return of a function call, in a syntax similar to this:

```
print accessorFunction()::must(); // Or something as close to it as possible

function accessorFunction(){
    returns (reference to)everything; // Or something as close to it as possible
}
```

I hope I've made the question clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you know the difference between classes and objects - you seem to be using them interchangeably. It's also worth noting that PHP doesn't have the notion of a static class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's NOT possible to call static methods this way:

```
print accessorFunction()::must();
```

But possible

```
$class_name = accessorFunction();
print $class_name::must();
```

Documentation - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of reference you're looking for, but you can always do:

```
print call_user_func( array( accessorFunction(), "must"));

function accessorFunction(){
    return 'everything';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use variable classes:

```
function accessorFunction() {
    return new everything();
}

$class = accessorFunction();
echo $class::must(); // go!
```

Comment: This solution instantiates the object, I want to keep it static if at all possible.

Comment: Fair enough. Strictly speaking, a static method shouldn't be called on an object - it should use the class that houses the static method.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleaner option would be to mix @nickb and @GeorgeBrighton solutions:

```
function accessorFunction() {
    return 'everything';
}

$class = accessorFunction();
echo $class::must(); // prints go!
```